# How can I use glide in fragment with kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a fragment and in "onViewCreated" I'm calling `Glide.with(requireActivity()).load(user.image).into(ivChannelImage)`. I've tried `Glide.with(requireContext()).load(user.image).into(ivChannelImage)`. It gives me java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException. `ivChannelImage` is an ImageView. How can I fix it?

Comment: what is `user.image` an url image?

Comment: Show all stacktrace

Comment: user.image is a string, should I use Uri.parse?

Comment: string is also fine